# Проблема с Sublime Text 3 после тега style

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

появилась внезапно проблема после написания тега style="" отключается подсветка и распознание синтаксиса  Как поправить ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не могу повторить вашу проблему. Скорее всего причина в локальных глюках из за плагинов или может нехватки памяти? На всякий случай опубликуйте код в виде текста, но сперва выключите все плагины, включите дефолтную цветовую схему и проверьте ещё раз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]